# How do I enable SASS line numbers in CSS output?

Tags: css, ruby, sass, compass-sass

How can I enable line numbers in CSS output if I am using SASS? I found an article but I didn't quite understand where to make the modifications

http://pivotallabs.com/users/damon/blog/articles/765-standup-04-07-2009-we-have-questions#comments

Could you help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's an option called `:line_comments` if you set this to true, Sass will place line numbers in your compiled output.

How to set this option depends on how you're using Sass. If it's in a Rails, Merb, or Rack application you can set `Sass::Plugin.options[:line_comments] = true`.

If you're using compass, set `line_comments = false` in your configuration file.

Comment: OK, I added 'line_comments = false' in the config.rb file, but still no change... I am using compass, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In compass.config, sass_options = { :line_comments => true }

Comment: There was a bug in compass that was recently fixed. If you can upgrade to 0.10.0.pre2 or greater it will work. Or you can do it kyle's way.

Comment: It worked! Thank you kyle and chris, I will update when it will be a stable version.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be using Sprockets and the [sprockets-sass](https://github.com/petebrowne/sprockets-sass) gem, you may need to do it like this:

```
Sprockets::Sass.options[:line_comments] = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested this monkey-patch:

```
# Had to use this instead as per comment by @glebtv https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/157
module Sass
    class Engine
      def initialize(template, options={})
        @options = self.class.normalize_options(options)
        @options[:debug_info] = true
        @template = template
      end
    end
end
```

The monkey-patch works, but I think this works even better: https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/pull/181

For now, you have to pull in rails-sass from the master branch.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0', git: 'https://github.com/rails/sass-rails.git', branch: 'master'
end
```