# How to disable comment generation in the css files when using sass and rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am using a standard rails 4.1.6 'rails new' gemset, with added bootstrap-sass

Here is the Gemfile (comments excluded) for the reference:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.6'
gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
gem 'slim', '2.1.0'
gem 'slim-rails', '2.1.5'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.2'
```

The app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss contains:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

/* my css stuff*/
.
.
.
```

When I open up the custom.css though for example firefox's view page source I see
something like:

```
/* line 142, /home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails4_1_6/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.2.0.2/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_scaffolding.scss */
.sr-only-focusable:active, .sr-only-focusable:focus {
 position: static;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0;
 overflow: visible;
 clip: auto;
}
```

My question is how do I disable the comments from generating?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable SASS line numbers in CSS output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824798/how-do-i-enable-sass-line-numbers-in-css-output)

Comment: The problem is that I don't use the gems noted in the link provided therefore I don't know which option to add and where to add it. As for the sass-rails the gem I use is 4.0.3.

Comment: The 2nd paragraph in the selected answer addresses Rails (which you *are* using).

Comment: Problem is I don't know where to actually put `Sass::Plugin.options[:line_comments] = false`
If I put it in the config/application.rb I get:
`<class:Application>': uninitialized constant Sass::Plugin (NameError)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `config.sass.line_comments = false` into `application.rb` file.

More info: https://github.com/rails/sass-rails 'example' section and http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#options

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this question. I had trouble finding the right syntax, and am still new to rails in general.